# Rename a class in Xcode: Refactor... is grayed out (disabled). Why?

Tags: iphone, xcode, refactoring

Why is **Refactor...** grayed out (disabled) in Xcode?

I'd like to rename a class.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Select the class's symbol in its header file - i.e. the bit just after `@interface`. Then the refactoring stuff should be enabled.

Comment: My class's header file has only @interface, no @class. But selecting the symbol after @interface seems to work.

Comment: @class if for forward declarations…s

Comment: This has been bothering me for quite some time also. Thanks!

Comment: Even this does not enable refactoring in xcode 4. I am becoming hopeless, why apple do not improve their Refactoring things. There is Eclipse to follow, how to do things!

Comment: @karim - it's never worked in Xcode, see my answer below for workaround that works every time

Answer (score 26):

If you are using Objective-C++ (i.e. mix Objective-C with C++ code) then refactoring is disabled in xcode since it does not support refactoring of C++ code.

Comment: Very sad, almost 2 years later and it still won't refactor the Objective-C objects.

Comment: @christophercotton Try almost 8 years later, and it still is not implemented.

Answer (score 7):

Refactor might also be disabled if affected files (most likely the file with your class in it) are not saved.

Comment: Saving a xib file in Interface Builder re-enabled Refactoring for me, when even relaunching Xcode wasn't helping, thanks!

Comment: +1 for this. Some corners of XCode still have rough areas and this is one of them. Sometimes if saving doesn't enable refactoring, rebuilding will.

Answer (score 6):

I've been using Xcode for 5 years now, and refactoring has never worked correctly (even xcode 4.6 has major bugs where it WILL corrupt your source code!).

The workaround has always been (still works 100%, even in cases where Apple's code fails)

1. use shift-command-f to find all uses of the file
2. select "replace" in the search settings
3. "replace-all"
4. do the following for the .h file, and REPEAT IT FOR THE .m FILE (if you have one):

   1. right click the original file, and select "show in finder"
   2. delete the file from xcode (select "delete references only" when asked)
5. rename the .h (and .m if you have one) in Finder
6. in Xcode, select "Product -> (hold down Alt) -> Clean Build Folder"
7. quit xcode (you can usually get away with not doing this - but NOTE: there are some other MAJOR bugs in Xcode where it crashes itself if you don't do this)
8. re-open xcode
9. drag/drop the .h and .m back into Xcode
10. wait a few seconds (some of Xcode's core methods are asynchronous - allowing it to corrupt your project)
11. finally, when it seems to be doing nothing (and your hard disk isn't making any noise any more): cmd-b to re-build

I have a 100% success rate with this method. I just tried refactoring with Apple's "Refactor -> Rename" in latest xcode and it failed - again!

(this time with the incorrect error: "Unable to determine the language of", one of those error messages where Apple put the wrong text in place)

Comment: Yep, I tried this recently (May 2014) and the Xcode official "refactor" menuoption is *still* broken, it *still* corrupts your source code. I am surprised that Apple staff aren't bothered by this.

Answer (score 3):

For me I realized Refactor was disabled because the Xcode project I had opened was referencing a Base SDK that was missing. Edit Project Settings and in the Build tab set the Base SDK to one that you have (like for me this was iOS 4.2). This enabled Refactor for me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to my project at finder, then change files name by **get info**.

After that, at **xcode -> Project Navigator** I delete the files.

At end, I click right on the class and **Add files to ...**, and add these files again.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Also, it could happen that you renamed the filename for the class, either outside xcode or by ctrl-clicking the filename and then renaming it.
xcode refuses to refactor if filename does not match with the class name.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your class' header file and find the line that looks similar to this:

```
@interface YourClassName
```

Right click on the class symbol (e.g. YourClassName) and you should be able to select Refactor -> Rename...

I just tried this and it works in Xcode 5.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit late, but I stumbled across this post because I was unable to refactor my "ViewController.swift" file to "WhateverViewController.swift".  I tried selecting the file in the Project Navigator and then selecting "Editor -> Refactor" from the top menu, but 'rename' is always greyed out.

Instead, what worked was selecting the ViewController name from the editor. So if you have:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
 // Code here...
}
```

Highlight the "ViewController" word and then select Refactor from the menu or right-click and select Refactor -> rename.

Hopefully that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem as well. I ran through trying to find missing SDKs, saving files, and looking for Objective-C++ code as mentioned above, and all it took to fix my machine was rebooting XCode.

Seems a little buggy still.

BTW, this was for XCode 4.0.1

Answer (score -1):

Refactoring works If you first change the file name in the project navigator.