# Xcode is stuck when trying to refactor a class

Tags: iphone, xcode, refactoring

Xcode gets stuck if I try to rename a class via refactoring.

It shows "Applying Changes" window and says "Please wait while changes are made." But changes are never made. It's stuck!

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The only thing you can do is raise a bug with apple

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem...and it's over two years later and I'm using Xcode 4.5

Comment: manual refactoring...? anyway, it is interesting how many people say it is a known bug, I've never experienced any issues with the refactor-feature, however my colleague always changes the Xcode settings back and forth, and the refactor-feature is not working on his computer at all...

Comment: Go to activity monitor and kill it, restart and try again.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem...and it's over three years later and I'm using Xcode 5.0

Comment: The frustrating part for me was that it partially renamed the class, so I have to restore from svn / xcode snapshot or manually revert.

Comment: I have this issue. It is now over four years later, and I'm using Xcode 6.1.

Comment: Over seven years later, this bug is going strong with Xcode 8.3.3 on macOS High Sierra!

Answer (score 5):

3 years later using Xcode 5, this is still a bug. Only thing to do is file a radar.

Only appears to happen some of the time however, since others have gotten it to rename a class in this SO question - [Rename a class in Xcode: Refactor... is grayed out (disabled). Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992381/rename-a-class-in-xcode-refactor-is-grayed-out-disabled-why?rq=1)

Comment: I just started seeing this behavior too, in Xcode 4.6.3 and Xcode 5 DP6.  Will do my refactoring in AppCode I guess.

Comment: It's amazing how much Xcode is behind other IDEs. Apple seems to lead in other areas, but their IDE is simply catastrophic.

Comment: I can add that in Xcode 6 this is still an issue. A simple extraction and all I got was  a continuous spinning wheel of doom :(

Comment: Using Xcode 6, and it's still freezing from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

Hold alt (option), and right click the Xcode icon, Force Quit. Open Xcode and do it again. Pain but solution.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to force XCode to quit via the Activity Monitor, and relaunch it.

### Open Activity Monitor:

1. CMD+Space (opens Spotlight search bar)
2. Type "Activity Monitor"... it'll likely show up at the top of the list before you finish typing the whole thing
3. Press enter if "Activity Monitor" app is highlighted in the spotlight list, or click on the  icon.

### Force Quit XCode:

1. Select "XCode" from the list to highlight it
2. Click the big STOP icon to force quit.

### Open XCode Again..

Answer (score 0):

it is not well solution but you can try this. first open terminal, then:

```
ps aux | grep Xcode
```

then get the PID from processes list. you will see something like that:

```
<username> 3055   0.0  5.1  4392432 429552   ??  S    11:46AM   1:48.16 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
```

here, 3055 means Xcode process name. There might be some child processes under Xcode, but you should choose one of plain Xcode process.

then call,

```
kill -9 PID
```

for my sample,

```
kill -9 3055
```

quick and dirty solution.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal, faster:

`killall Xcode`