# Xcode -- mass renaming of classes

Tags: xcode, refactoring, rename

I want to rename about 100 classes in my Xcode project.  It would be painful to change every filename, then do a search and replace on the name of each class in question.

Is there a better way?

The change in question involves changing a prefix -- think of what Apple would need to do if they decided to rename all the classes in their "NS" framework to start with "MS".  Unfortunately, the two caps in question do start some words in the project which are not among the class names in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have C++, Shaggy's answer will probably work for you.  But in my case, the answer appears to be that there is no better way.

Answer (score 3):

If your version of Xcode is reasonably up-to-date, you can right-click on the symbol name in the editor and choose "Refactor..." which will take care of both renaming files and renaming symbols (with the appropriate checkbox enabled).

Comment: @WilliamJockusch Make sure you are clicking on the symbol in a source file and not in, say, a comment. Using the same version here.

Comment: OK, I see the problem, I'm using Objective C++, which according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992381/rename-a-class-in-xcode-refactor-is-grayed-out-disabled-why) disables refactoring.

Comment: @WilliamJockusch  Doh. I wonder if the Xcode 4 pre-release would do it?