# Rename in XCode wrtting C++

Tags: c++, xcode

when i choose file, and find refactor->rename, 
it indicate Xcode can only refactor C or Object-C code.
 is that mean i can never change my file name?

Of course, if i directly change file name in disk, that will give me error.

Comment: Some discussion in here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992381/rename-a-class-in-xcode-refactor-is-grayed-out-disabled-why>

Comment: You can rename files in Xcode if you click on the actual file in your tree view and hit 'Enter'.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly change it the old fashioned way. Slow double tapping a file name in the Project tree lets me rename it. After that you just need to fix all references to this file (compile -> fix errors) and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

To rename a C++ file in Xcode as of version 9 you can either

- slow press a file twice and rename it the old fashion way (@Karthik)
- Have the file selected at the left pane and hit tab or enter

You have to fix all the references yourself after renaming C++ files.